# Handling UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to handle the negative testing scenario i.e. Kafka topic is not found.
I am setting the Kafka topic wrong purposefully. And I am seeing the below log....

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testing.topic.ayan.kafka.topic.v222 not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

I don't want the thread to be blocked for 60000 ms. So I have set the "max.block.ms" property to adjust the max block time.

Is there any other way to handle this scenario? Why Kafka core is not handling this on its own?

Comment: What is there to handle? You've explicitly tried to make it poll from a topic which might get created externally at some point in the future. It's letting you know the topic currently doesn't exist, but it's not a fatal error and will keep trying

Comment: I agree, but my business requirement is bit different. I don't want my threads to be blocked for 60000 ms. I want to throw error, immediately, stating that provided topic is not found.  "max.block.ms" setting this prop is doing that job. I want to know if there is any other solution for handling topic name not found scenario.

Comment: You can use `AdminClient.describeTopic` before creating a consumer and throw some custom exception

Comment: I am trying to handle it from producer side. While producing the message to wrong Kafka  topic, I want to handle the scenario.

Comment: Like I said, 1) You can't (assuming auto-topic creation is disabled) 2) You can use AdminClient before the producer is created to prevent it from ever _trying_ to connect to the topic instead. Otherwise, why are you trying to produce to a topic that doesn't exist in the first place?